# Operator norm of symmetric Markov kernel acting on $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $(S,\mathcal B)$ be a measurable space, $\pi$ be a Markov kernel on $(S,\mathcal B)$ and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(S,\mathcal B)$ invariant with respect to $\pi$. Let $L^2_0(\mu):=\left\{f\in L^2(\mu):\int f\:{\rm d}\mu=0\right\}=\left\{f\in L^2(\mu):f\perp 1\right\}$ and $\gamma(\pi)$ denote the operator norm of $$\pi f:=\int\pi(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in L^2_0(\mu),$$ i.e. $$\gamma(\pi)=\left\|\pi\right\|_{\mathfrak L(L^2_0(\mu))}=\sup_{f\perp1}\frac{\left\|\pi f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}.$$

On page 48 of [this lecture notes](https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/MarkovProcesses1920/MarkovProcesses1920.pdf), we can find the following:

[image]

> The last identity seems to be wrong to me. As [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3432096/47771), we should have $$\gamma(\pi)=\sup_{f\perp1}\frac{\color{red}{|}\langle\pi f,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\color{red}{|}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}\tag1$$ instead. On the other hand, the quantity without the absolute value should be $$\sup_{f\perp1}\frac{\langle\pi f,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(\pi)}\lambda,\tag1$$ where $\sigma(\pi)$ denotes the spectrum of $\pi$. Am I missing something or is there a mistake in the lecture notes?